# What can we say about $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\phi \left( Ax\right) \frac{\phi \left( x\right) }{\Phi \left( x\right) }dx$?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Let

$$\phi \left( x\right) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\text{ and }
\Phi \left( x\right) =\int_{-\infty }^{x}\phi \left( t\right) dt$$

be the pdf and cdf of the standard normal distribution.

If $A\neq 0$, what can we say about
$
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\phi \left( Ax\right) \frac{\phi \left(
x\right) }{\Phi \left( x\right) }dx?
$
Is there some nice formula for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no nice closed formula, but if $a$ is large enough, say $a\geq 1$, we may approximate $\frac{1}{\Phi(x)}$ with $2-2x \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}+\frac{4 x^2}{\pi }$ and get:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\phi(x)\cdot \phi(ax)}{\Phi(x)}\,dx \approx (2+\pi+a^2\pi)\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi^3(1+a^2)^3}}.$$
Another approximation that works quite well (always for large $a$s) is $\frac{1}{\Phi(x)}\approx 2 e^{\frac{x^2}{\pi}-x\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}$, and that leads to the better-looking:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\phi(x)\cdot \phi(ax)}{\Phi(x)}\,dx \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi(1+a^2)-2}}\,\exp\left(\frac{1}{\pi(a^2+1)-2}\right).$$